# Adding Facebook SDK to a project without CocoaPods in Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, facebook

I'm not able to build my app with the Facebook SDK in iOS 10. I've included both the "Bolts.framework" and "FBSDKCoreKit.framework" frameworks to my projects. I've also added my Facebook SDK folder to the "Framework Search Paths" in "Build Settings". This is the folder that contains these frameworks.

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to resolve it. My project compiled fine in Xcode 9 but won't compile in Xcode 10. Is there another step I'm missing in Xcode 10?

```
'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
```

UPDATE: Xcode seems to not be able to find the frameworks. This is the error I'm getting. I dragged the frameworks into Xcode from that folder. If I right-click on the framework and click "Show in Finder" it goes right to the frameworks so I don't understand my Xcode can't locate them.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F~/MY_FOLDER/FacebookSDK'
ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

UPDATE 2: Even if I remove that folder from my build options Xcode still complains it can't find the frameworks. I have to completely delete them from my project in order to build successfully.

Comment: Did you try cleaning build folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it's still not working.

Comment: Hey, did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem @BerryBlue